# NSIS - Remove leading and trailing whitespaces from a string

Tags: nsis

I want to trim my textbox value in NSIS, for that i have used the below link

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Remove_leading_and_trailing_whitespaces_from_a_string
 Problem with my solution is, above example remove the entire text followed by the text say example my text is something like this " First Name ". when i call the trim method it removes Entire Name itself and giving the result as "First". But i want to remove only leading and trailing whitespace. Not the inbetween spaces.

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me:

```
Function Trim
    Exch $R1 ; Original string
    Push $R2
Loop:
    StrCpy $R2 "$R1" 1
    StrCmp "$R2" " " TrimLeft
    StrCmp "$R2" "$\r" TrimLeft
    StrCmp "$R2" "$\n" TrimLeft
    StrCmp "$R2" "$\t" TrimLeft
    GoTo Loop2
TrimLeft:
    StrCpy $R1 "$R1" "" 1
    Goto Loop
Loop2:
    StrCpy $R2 "$R1" 1 -1
    StrCmp "$R2" " " TrimRight
    StrCmp "$R2" "$\r" TrimRight
    StrCmp "$R2" "$\n" TrimRight
    StrCmp "$R2" "$\t" TrimRight
    GoTo Done
TrimRight:
    StrCpy $R1 "$R1" -1
    Goto Loop2
Done:
    Pop $R2
    Exch $R1
FunctionEnd
!define Trim "!insertmacro Trim"
 !macro Trim ResultVar String
  Push "${String}"
  Call Trim
  Pop "${ResultVar}"
!macroend


Section

${Trim} $0 " First Name "
MessageBox mb_ok "|$0|"

SectionEnd
```

Maybe you could edit your question to include example code that fails?